# Google App Script to Retrieve Version Control

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, version-control

I am trying to find a command that will enable the retrieval of the named versions within the version history of Google Sheet files within a folder.  I already have the code to call the name of the files, the updated date etc, but I need the details of the named version that is currently in the folder.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to access them via Google Drives API

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

If you enable the Drive API in Apps Script you will be able to use the Google Drive API method `revisions().list` which lists the versions of the file specified containing all the desired details of the revision (Id, name, etc).

This is a sample code of how to achieve this:

```js
  function myF() {
  // Get the file id
    var fileId = '1KNJxE7pdDGGgO3zWcaMu1Pe1z1b_-h2A9a26rq9TXps';
    
    // Get an array with all the revisions
    var revisions = Drive.Revisions.list(fileId);
    
    // Iterate through each revision
    for(i=0; i<revisions.items.length;i++){
    
    // Get each revision 
    var revision = revisions.items[i];
    
    // Log each revision with all its details
    Logger.log(revision);
  }
 }
```

[Here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive#listing_revisions) you can see another example on how to do this in the official documentation site.

I hope this has helped you. Let me know if you need anything else or if you did not understood something. :)

Comment: Hi @TORJL yes, you are absolutely right, I dont remember when I wrote this but it was not what I intended. I have updated the answer with the **right piece of code that works** and I also have left you a link to more info about this topic. Sorry for the confusion!